# How to uninstall "Installations" under System Report?

Tags: macos

[image: System Report Installations]

I was wondering how I can access these five programs that I downloaded without having the proper knowledge of uninstalling them. They have been messing with my system audio output through the speaker and I am trying to locate and delete them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In those cases i use a little app called [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/).

The just drag the app in question in to it and it will find all associated files to that program and ask you if you want to delete them.

If you do not have the original app any more, you could use Terminal and find the files and delete them.

type `mdfind TechSmith` and see what comes up

Answer (score 1):

It's part of [Camtasia](https://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html). You can install or uninstall the audio component from Camtasia itself

Camtasia > Prefs > Recording tab

[image]

*source:* [Camtasia (Mac): System Audio Recording Guide](https://support.techsmith.com/hc/en-us/articles/203727518-Camtasia-Mac-System-Audio-Recording-Guide)

Answer (score 0):

AppZapper might work, the list of installations is taken from the installer receipt database. AppZapper uses the same database.